# React Native IOS - ImagePickerManager.h file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

This build error only occurs in iOS. It builds fine in Android. Seems like the error is looking for a file called ImagePickerManager.h which is part of the react-native-file-picker library. Any idea how to fix this? Please refer to the screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFihT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-picker

> iOS This component does not currently work on iOS, instead use
>   react-native-document-picker

For image picker you can use this :

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker